# Call java class from matlab

Tags: java, matlab

I'm trying to call a java class from matlab(2010a) but isn't working. I tried to follow [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/99993-how-do-i-call-a-simple-hello-world-java-program-in-matlab) tutorial, but didn't work.

```
public class Helloworld {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
}
```

1)I created this class at netbeans and compiled it using Java 1.6.0_12 (the same that is used at  matlab 2010a).
2)I added the generate jar file at dynamic class path, using this command

```
javaaddpath('C:\Users\xx\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Helloworld\dist\Helloworld.jar');
```

3) I used this command, to create a object

```
o = HelloWorld
```

4)But matlab shows me this message

```
??? Undefined function or variable 'HelloWorld'.
```

Any idea about how to solve my issue?

Comment: 1) Do you actually have Helloworld.jar at the location your specifying? 2) Could you post your Matlab code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the package and I hadn`t send the (empty)argument to the main function.

My full code:

```matlab
javaaddpath('C:\Users\xx\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Helloworld\dist\Helloworld.jar');
%call class, inclugind the package!
% o = helloworld.Helloworld;
o = helloworld.Helloworld();
%call java method, including the argument
javaMethod('main', o,[]);
```